# Cannot enable site on apache

Tags: apache-2.4, virtualhost, linode

I am trying to add virtual host for a site but cannot enable it.

I have added the configuration file(.conf) in site-available folder. when I try to enable it by running

```
a2ensite <site.net>.conf
```

it says,

```
ERROR: Site <site.net> does not exist!
```

There are already few other sites running on the server without any hiccup. Facing this issue for the first time.

Screenshot:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You post the output of `sites-availble`, the correct folder should be `sites-available`. You either somehow managed to rename the directory with all configs in it and the next restart of apache will break all your sites, or you created a second folder with configs in it, from which apache won't read your new file. Either way, fix the directory name.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the `.conf` suffix for `a2ensite`:

```
a2ensite  <site.net>
```

should work.

If not, you can always manually create a symlink into `sites-enabled`.

Comment: tried without .conf already. same error. I understand, it can be done manually. but the question is, why it's not working in the first place.

Comment: Additionally, tried now to create the symlink manually. The file was created but it was empty. @sven